# The mean curvature of a hypersurface

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

It is well known to geometric analyst that the scalar curvature of a Riemannian manifold can be decomposed to two parts: one part has a divergence structure and the other part consists of lower order terms. My question is for the mean curvature of a hypersurface in a Euclidean space, dose it have a similar structure? Has any author considered a decomposition of this kind? Any reference will be useful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just comment that for a graph in a Euclidean space the mean curvature has a divergence structure.

Comment: The formula for graphical mean curvature is naturally in a divergence form.  A hypersurfsce is locally graphical, so that gives what you want.  Any book on minimal surfaces will give you the formula, the one I have in front of me is colding minicozzi  eqn 1.6 on p 2. The 0 could replaced by mean curvature you're interested in nonminimal surfaces.

Comment: Thanks, Otis. Actually if we assume f is the immersion, I want to get a formula of the mean curvature which has two parts: one part consists of second derivatives of f and has a divergence structure and the other part consists of at most first derivatives of f

Comment: Yong, you might want to take a look at the formula Otis has referred you to and then let us know whether it meets your needs or not. If not, you should perhaps present the formulas you do have and explain why they aren't what you want.

Comment: Thanks Deane. I have looked at the formula Otis told me. But I still do not know how it can satisfy my need. Actually I want to define some Mass for hypersurfaces, which is similar to the famous ADM mass. To do this I need a proper decomposition for the mean curvature. 

Comment: Actually I can make my question more clear. We know for a graph the mean curvature has a divergence form. Hence I am curious about whether we can give a decomposition of the mean curvature to two parts, such that one part has a divergence structure and the other part is zero, in the case of graphs.

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to post an image without a big song and dance. If you go to [MY STUFF](http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/bib.html) and open the Michigan Math J. 1991, page 256 has the formula when the hypersurface is given as the level set of a smooth function. It is just a rotated version of the graph formula, as it must be. Meanwhile, the mean curvature is just a dimension constant times the divergence of the (oriented) unit normal, where it does not matter whther you take the divergence on the manifold or extend the unit normal field off the manifold and use the ambient divergence. All the same. I do not see how   you are going to separate out first and second order derivatives.

Wait, I can try to typeset:

$$   n H = \frac{1}{|\nabla F|} \; \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}   \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \left( \delta_{ij} - \frac{F_i F_j}{|\nabla F|^2} \right) F_{ij}   $$
That actually looks correct. Good for me. Level set of the function $F$ and $H$ is the mean curvature with one of the choices of unit normal field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Will. I will try to study your paper. If it works for me, I will tell you. Thanks again.

Comment: Could you tell me the name of your paper ? I can't open your link, thanks.

Comment: @lanse7pty  it was  http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Michigan_1991.pdf